# Question about step in proof of Young's convolution Inequality

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, inequality, convolution

This is the inequality we are attempting to prove: Let $f \in \mathcal{L}^p(\mathbb{R}^n), \ g \in \mathcal{L}^1(\mathbb{R}^n)$ and $1 \leq p < \infty$. Then $f * g$ is defined almost everywhere with $f*g \in \mathcal{L}^p(\mathbb{R}^n)$ and
$$ \| f * g \|_p \leq \| f \|_p \cdot \|g \|_1. $$

The proof goes as follows:

WLOG we can assume $g \geq 0 $ and $\| g \|_1 = 1$, therefore $ \mu := g\lambda^n $ is a probability measure.

He then goes on to use the Jensen inequality to obtain the result. Why are we able to assume WLOG that $\| g \|_1 = 1$? I'm also not really understanding what $ g\lambda^n$ even means let alone understanding why it would be a probability measure.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Very welcome to the MSC. Please provide more details on the sets and product used in the statement. You may also, provide a link to the paper you are working on.

Comment: Well $\mathcal{L}^p(\mathbb{R}^n)$ is the set of functions $f: \mathbb{R}^n \to  \mathbb{R}$ for which the p-th power of the absolute value is Lebesgue integrable, $f * g$ is just the convolution of $f$ and $g$. This isn't for a paper I'm writing this is for a course I'm taking in University.

Comment: please include the definitions in the question to increase the chance of getting an answer. Precisely define the norms, the sets, and the convolution.

Comment: Your question is far from being clear. Please follow the comment from Amir and define ALL objects in your question. For example, I assume that $\lambda^n$ is the Lebesgue measure on $\mathbb R^n$, but I am not even sure about this... Also, who is "he"? Can you include a link to your resource?